# Should I keep using mocks and stubs in domain testing?

Tags: unit-testing, domain-driven-design

I am creating an n-tier application following DDD. I have test projects for each individual layer.  Right now I am using FakeItEasy to create mocks and stubs to run domain tests because I still haven't implemented my data access layer.

My question is, should I keep using mocks and stubs to test domain layer even after implementing data access layer so the test data is not depending on DAL ? Or should I use actual data retrieved through DAL to run domain tests?

Comment: What do you mean by domain tests ? Domain shouldn't call DAL, so no need for mocks or stubs when testing only the Domain layer. You might need them in tests that verify Application layer objects, though.

Comment: It's bit confusing. The guide that I followed for N-tire application creation encouraged using stubs and mocks in domain testing. How would you test it without mocking data? Can you please point me at a tutorial or a book that demonstrates how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Source of confusion might be what you put behind "domain testing". What's tested ? What's mocked out ? Can you post an example of such a test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From unit testing point of view you should be using mocks and stubs. On of the traits of good unit tests is **isolation**, which means they shouldn't rely on external components (like data access).

However, you might want to (or need to) have another type of tests<sup>1</sup> - [**integration tests**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) - which allow you to test components together (in your case you would test integration between domain and data access). In those tests you use *actual implementations* rather than mocks/stubs.

<sub>1: *Additionally* to unit tests of course, *not instead of*</sub>

Comment: Thanks! So I will do another set of testing to see if everything is working together.